# Checking if there are two same values inside two 2D arrays

Tags: c, function, multidimensional-array, nested

I am trying to create a snakes and ladders game in c. In the game of snakes and ladders there are ladders that bring you up to the board and snakes that take you down. I am making a project wherein my board can only have one up tile (ladder) and one down tile (snake) per row. I was able to create two functions called `up_num` and `down_num` that randomly generate 6 values per array that ensures that there will only be one up tile and one down tile in my board. My problem however is that there are times wherein an up tile will have the same value as a down tile. This means that there are times that one of the elements in my up array will appear as an element in my down array. I am trying to make a function that checks my two arrays called `up[][]` and `down[][]`. The reason as to why they are 2D arrays is because I want one number to be a tile that takes the player up or down the board, while the other number will be the tile that the player will land on.

Here is the function for checking I have made so far.

```
void check(int up[][2], int down[][2])
{
    printf("\n\n");

    int h = 0, i, j, k, l, m = 0;
    int check[12];
    int check_up[6];
    int check_down[6];
    int counter = 0;

    for (k = 0; k < 6; k++) {
        if (counter == 0) {
            h = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for(j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
                    check_up[h++] = up[i][j];
                    check_down[h++] = down[i][j];
                }
            }
        } 

        counter++;
        for (j = 0; j < 6; j++) {
            if (check_up[k] == check_down[j]) {
                up_num(up);
                down_num(down);
                k = 0;
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d, ", up[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n");

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            printf("%d, ", down[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

I still get duplicate values sometimes and I cant think of a way to solve the issue. I tried creating a nested loop that restarts whenever a duplicate value is found, then I call the two functions I created beforehand to generate random values again that will ensure that there will only be one up tile and one down tile in my board. I made sure to check if maybe the two functions I created were the problem but after a while I figured that it was not. I just have a problem on checking the values of the 2D arrays on making sure that an element in one array will not appear in the other array.

Comment: Are you sure about using the same variable `h` for both `check_up` and `check_down`? And more importantly, should you really increase `h` twice (and skip every second elements of those arrays, and probably also go out of bounds of them)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I would like to ask what did you mean by skipping every second element of the arrays?

Comment: Lets say `h == 0`, then `check_up[h++] = up[i][j];` will assign to `check_up[0]` and `check_down[h++] = down[i][j];` will assign to `check_down[1]`. Next iteration you will assign to `check_up[2]` and `check_down[3]`. And so on. You never assign to `check_up[1]` or `check_down[0]` for example.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to test out your code by creating a two-dimensional array for snakes and ladders, but there were function information missing to get a clean compile (e.g. no definition for the "up_num()" and "down_num()" functions).  And by attempting to interpret what your ultimate goal was of not having multiple ladders or snakes in the same row, and also not place a ladder and a snake at the same position, the code for performing these tests actually seemed overly complicated.

I may be way off base in my interpretation of what this test function should do, but following is a refactored version of the function along with a "main" program that builds a simple two-dimensional array for both the snakes and the ladders and then tests out some various scenarios.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define ROWS 6                      /* To give flexibility to board size and design */
#define COLS 12

int check(int up[ROWS][COLS], int down[ROWS][COLS])
{
    int counterLadder = 0;
    int counterSnakes = 0;

    /* Testing for duplicate ladders and/or snakes in a row */

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            if (up[i][j] == 1)
                counterLadder++;
            if (counterLadder > 1)
            {
                printf("More than one ladder was found in row %d\n", i);
                return 1;
            }
            if (down[i][j] == 1)
                counterSnakes++;
            if (counterSnakes > 1)
            {
                printf("More than one snake was found in row %d\n", i);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Checking to see that a ladder and a snake do not exist at the same location */

    counterLadder = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            if ((up[i][j] == down[i][j]) && (up[i][j] == 1))
            {
                counterLadder++;
                printf("A ladder and a snake are located at row %d, column %d\n", i, j);
                return 1;
            }
        }

        if (counterLadder > 1)
            return 1;
    }

    printf("All clear\n");

    return 0;
}

int main()              /* Basically a simple test harness program to build and then test out location issues with the ladder and snake locations   */
{
    int Ladder[ROWS][COLS], Snakes[ROWS][COLS];

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++)
        {
            Ladder[i][j] = 0;
            Snakes[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }

    if(check(Ladder, Snakes) == 1)
        printf("Some type of error occurred - retry\n");

    Ladder[2][4] = 1;
    Ladder[2][9] = 1;

    if(check(Ladder, Snakes) == 1)
        printf("Some type of error occurred - retry\n");

    Ladder[2][9] = 0;
    Snakes[2][4] = 1;

    if(check(Ladder, Snakes) == 1)
        printf("Some type of error occurred - retry\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the length of the refactored code, but I wanted to give you the whole thing as food for thought.  When I ran this example, the following terminal output was created.

```
craig@Vera:~/C_Programs/Console/SnakesAndLadders/bin/Release$ ./SnakesAndLadders 
All clear
More than one ladder was found in row 2
Some type of error occurred - retry
A ladder and a snake are located at row 2, column 4
Some type of error occurred - retry
```

As I said, I might be missing some subtle issue in your testing, but that seemed to simplify the testing for duplications and overlaps.  Review it as your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

Pardon me for saying this, but you may be coming at the problem from the wrong direction. Instead of making up a single pair of board locations (or a number of pairs), it would be better to be checking for your criteria as each candidate pair is generated.

Below is an approach that could still use some polish. A game board is allocated from the heap, `calloc()` setting all elements to 0. Then, a cell index is randomly selected. If the cell value is 0, the cell can be used; a non-zero value indicating the cell is already used and a different cell must be selected. Then, with some convoluted summing and another random offset, another *vacant* cell is found. These two cells form a pair that is both ends of either a snake or a ladder. Notice that the value stored at each "*end*" of the pair is its partner's address. Not provided is the code that determines the role of the pair during the game.

Translation is used as the array is actually 1D, but manipulated as if it were 2D.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROWS 12
#define COLS 10
#define NELEM 12 // eg 6 snakes and 6 ladders

void show( int *pb, int rows, int cols ) {
    printf( "    " );
    for( int c = 0; c < cols; c++ ) // column titles
        printf( " %-2d ", c+1 );
    putchar( '\n' );

    for( int r = 0; r < rows; r++ ) {
        printf( "  %c ", r + 'A' ); // row title
        for( int c = 0; c < cols; c++ ) {
            if( !pb[ r * cols + c ] ) // vacant??
                printf( "=== " );
            else {
                int rw = pb[ r * cols + c ] / cols;
                int cw = pb[ r * cols + c ] % cols;
                printf( "%c%-2d ", rw + 'A', cw + 1 ); // terse address of partner
            }
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int *gen( int nElem, int rows, int cols ) {
    int n = rows * cols;
    int *pb = calloc( n, sizeof *pb ); // 1D version of 2D game board
    /* TODO: verify success */

    while( nElem ) {
        int e1, e2;
        e1 = 1 + (rand() % (n/2)); // one end
        if( !pb[e1] ) { // vacant??
            do {
                e2 = ( e1 + cols + rand()%(n-2*cols) )%n; // diff >= 1 row
            } while( pb[e2] ); // until another vacant found
            pb[e1] = e2; // address of partner
            pb[e2] = e1; // same
            nElem--;
        }
    }

    return pb; // game board established
}

int main( void ) {
    srand( time( 0 ) );

    int *pb = gen( NELEM, ROWS, COLS );
    show( pb, ROWS, COLS );
    free( pb );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
  A === === === === === === G6  === === ===
  B G9  H4  === H1  === === === H6  === ===
  C === I3  I5  I1  === === === === J1  === // eg "C2" <==> "I3". Snake or Ladder TBD
  D === === === === === === === === === ===
  E === === === K3  === K6  === === === ===
  F === === === === === L8  === === === ===
  G === === === === === A7  === === B1  ===
  H B4  === === B2  === B8  === === === ===
  I C4  === C2  === C3  === === === === ===
  J C9  === === === === === === === === ===
  K === === E4  === === E6  === === === ===
  L === === === === === === === F6  === ===
```

TODO: Ensure that the start 'square' and end 'square' are excluded from used cells. Neither of those `squares' should be a departure/arrival square.

Afterthought: Having established 'n' non-conflicting pairs, recognise that the "top end" of a ladder is a "neutral" destination, as is the "tail" of a snake. Work out a 'parity' loop that finds non-zero cells. If a cell and its partner are both non-zero, reset one end to zero ("neutral") according to the parity counter. This leaves a matrix full of zeros except for those "special" cells that point to a destination partner. Either the player advances up a ladder, or suffers a heart-wrenching loss in position sliding down a snake.

---

**Update:**
With some unexpected free time, the OP's desire to limit each row to have, at most, one snake head or ladder bottom ("a one-way *wormhole*"), has been addressed. The annotated code below seems to work. There remain some "print debugging" statements that may be *switched on* to trace the code's execution.

The chief addition is two "32 bit registers"; one for snakes, one for ladders. When a wormhole entry cell has been determined (for snake or ladder), one bit of the register corresponding to that cell's row is set. Subsequent iterations to place a snake/ladder check the appropriate bit, rejecting proffered cell pairs that would have more than one wormhole entry per row. (A snake's head AND a ladder bottom on one row are acceptable.)

The board's dimensions (max 32x32) and number of snake/ladder pairs could be supplied by command line arguments, and although currently unchecked, must make sense. To ensure a minimum length of 2 for snakes/ladders, the number of either cannot exceed # of rows minus 2. Otherwise, the program will loop indefinitely trying to fulfill an impossible request.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ROWS 12
#define COLS 10
#define NELEM 8 // eg 8 snakes and 8 ladders

void show( int *pb, int rows, int cols, char *title ) {
    puts( title );

    // column titles
    printf( "  " );
    for( int c = 0; c < cols; c++ )
        printf( "%-2d ", c );
    putchar( '\n' );

    for( int r = 0; r < rows; r++ ) {
        printf( "%c ", r + 'A' ); // row labels
        for( int c = 0; c < cols; c++ ) {
            if( !pb[ r * cols + c ] )
                printf( "== " ); // empty (might have shown destination)
            else {
                int pos = abs( pb[ r * cols + c ] ); // have -'ve destination values
                printf( "%c%-2d", 'A' + pos / cols, pos % cols );
            }
        }
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}

int *gen( int nElem, int rows, int cols ) {
    int nSnk = nElem, nLdr = nElem;
    int n = rows * cols;
    int *pb = calloc( n, sizeof *pb ); // allocate the board

    nElem += nElem; // equal number of snakes and ladders
    uint32_t rowSnk = 0; // bitarray of used rows for snake heads
    uint32_t rowLdr = 0; // bitarray of used rows for ladder bottoms

    while( nSnk || nLdr ) { // until both down counters reach zero
        int lo = 1 + (rand() % (n-2-cols-cols)); // reduced range

        if( pb[lo] ) {
            // printf( "in use\n" );
            continue;
        }

        int hi = cols + cols + (rand() % (n-2-cols-cols));
        if( pb[hi] ) {
            // printf( "in use\n" );
            continue;
        }

        if( abs( (lo - hi) / cols ) < 2 ) {
            // printf( "too short; not interesting\n" );
            continue;
        }

#   define min(a,b) ( (a) < (b) ? (a) : (b) )
#   define max(a,b) ( (a) < (b) ? (b) : (a) )
        int dprt = nElem % 2 ? min(lo,hi) : max(lo,hi); // depart from
#   undef min
#   undef max
        int arrv = dprt == lo ? hi : lo; // arrive at
        int drow = dprt / cols; // departure row
        uint32_t *accum = dprt < arrv ? &rowLdr : &rowSnk; // point at counter

        if( *accum & (1 << drow) ) {
            // printf( "row used already" );
            continue;
        }

        // got a pair of cells that work...
        pb[dprt] =     arrv; // partner
        pb[arrv] = 0 - dprt; // partner encoded as -'ve
        *accum |= (1 << drow); // set applicable counter's bit marking departure row used
        if( dprt < arrv ) nLdr--; else nSnk--; // decrement either ladder or snake counter
        nElem--; // decrement affects parity. parity determines trying for snake or ladder

// some "useful" print debugging info...
// printf( "lo[%3d](%4d) hi[%3d](%4d)", lo, pb[lo], hi, pb[hi] );
// printf( " dprt(%3d) arrv(%3d) drow(%2d)", dprt, arrv, drow );
// printf( " - %-6s -", dprt < arrv ? "Ladder" : "Snake" );
// printf( "  rowSnk %04X  rowLdr %04X", rowSnk, rowLdr );
// printf( "  nSnk %d  nLdr %d ", nSnk, nLdr );
// putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return pb;
}

int *prune( int *pb, int n ) { // set those -'ve destinations to zero for display.
    while( n-- )
        if( pb[n] < 0 ) pb[n] = 0;

    return pb;
}

int main( void ) {
    srand( time( 0 ) );

    int *pb = gen( NELEM, ROWS, COLS );
    show( pb, ROWS, COLS, "departures & arrivals" ); // show both ends
    show( prune( pb, ROWS * COLS ), ROWS, COLS, "departures only" );

    free( pb );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
departures & arrivals
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
A == == J1 == == == == == == ==
B == D6 == I7 == K7 == H5 == ==
C == == == H3 F6 == E6 == == ==
D == G8 G2 == == == B1 == == ==
E == == == == == J0 C6 == == ==
F == == == == == J6 C4 == L7 ==
G == == D2 == I4 == == == D1 ==
H == == == C3 == B7 == == K9 ==
I == == == == G4 == == B3 == ==
J E5 A2 == L6 == == F5 == == ==
K == == == == == == == B5 == H8
L == == == == == == J3 F8 == ==
departures only
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
A == == J1 == == == == == == ==
B == == == == == == == H5 == ==
C == == == H3 == == == == == ==
D == == G2 == == == B1 == == ==
E == == == == == J0 C6 == == ==
F == == == == == == C4 == L7 ==
G == == == == I4 == == == D1 ==
H == == == == == == == == K9 ==
I == == == == == == == B3 == ==
J == == == == == == F5 == == ==
K == == == == == == == B5 == ==
L == == == == == == J3 == == ==
```

Alternative thoughts: model determination of 2nd cell (loosely) on the moves of a knight in chess (instead of generating a 2nd random value). "1 cell left/right of start cell and 2 or 3 cells up or down." Desirable to have more *vertical* and less *horizontal* for snakes or ladders.